# Angular2 - pass ASYNC data to child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue, with passing async data to child component. I trying to write dynamic form generator. Issue starts when I try to call json via Observable and pass it into child component.

service:

```
generateSearchFields2(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.API + 'searchFields')
            .map((res:Response) => {
                res.json().data as any;
                for (var i = 0; i < res.json().data.length; i++) {
                    var searchField = res.json().data[i];
                    switch (searchField.component) {
                        case "TextboxQuestion": 

                            let TXQ: TextboxQuestion = new TextboxQuestion({
                                key: searchField.key,
                                label: searchField.label,
                                value: searchField.value,
                                required: searchField.required,
                                order: searchField.order
                            });
                            this.searchFieldModels.push(TXQ);
                            console.log("TXQ: ", TXQ, this.searchFieldModels);
                            break;
                        case "DropdownQuestion": 

                            let DDQ: DropdownQuestion = new DropdownQuestion({
                                key: searchField.key,
                                label: searchField.label,
                                required: searchField.required,
                                options: searchField.options,
                                order: searchField.order
                            });
                            this.searchFieldModels.push(DDQ);
                            console.log("TXQ: ", DDQ, this.searchFieldModels);
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert("DEFAULT");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return this.searchFieldModels.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Component Parent:

```
generateSearchFields2() {
    this.service.generateSearchFields2()
      .subscribe(res => this.searchFields = res)
  }
```

Iam passing variable via INPUT directive in parent template to child: `[searchFields]="searchFields"`

Issue is in child component, where `searchField` has undefined value. In this child I pass value to another service, to create formContros, but I got undefined there also. Data missing starts here, in child:

```
@Input() searchFields: SearchBase<any>[] = [];

ngOnInit() {   
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.searchFields);
    console.log("ONINIT DYNAMIC FORM COMPONENT: ", this.searchFields);

  }
```

Please for hint how I can pass async variable, to not loose data meantime

Answer (score 6):

You can make `@Input() searchFields` a setter

```
private _searchFields: SearchBase<any>[] = [];
@Input() set searchFields(value SearchBase<any>[]) {
  if(value != null) {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.searchFields);
    console.log("ONINIT DYNAMIC FORM COMPONENT: ", this.searchFields);
  }
}

get searchFields() : SearchBase<any>[] {
  return this.searchFields;
}
```

You can also use [ngOnChanges()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) which is called every time an input is updated, but a setter is usually more convenient except perhaps when the executed code depends on multiple inputs being set.

Comment: can you please  explain more about the difference between setter and ngOnChanges() ?

Answer (score 1):

In the `ngOnInit` event the `data` which comes from the `parent` is not bound yet. So your `searchFields` is `undefined` yet. You can use it in `NgAfterViewInit` component lifecycle event.

```
@Input() searchFields: SearchBase<any>[] = [];

ngAfterViewInit() {   
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.searchFields);
    console.log("ONINIT DYNAMIC FORM COMPONENT: ", this.searchFields);
}
```

For other cases you can see **[Angular2 Component Lifecycle events](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)**