# How to pass data from parent component to child component angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

Trying to pass the array value from the parent component to the child component using httpclient get method. So, I have used an input decorator. But, In my code, I am not able to pass the array value. Because the child component is loaded before the parent component. That's why i am not able to pass the data inside the get method. How to resolve this issue?

app.component.ts:

```
    public allData = []; 
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {} 
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/data.json').subscribe((data) => {
      this.allData = data;
      console.log('GetData');
      console.log(data);
    });
    }
```

auto.component.ts:

```
  @Input() data: Array<string> = [];
  public rateData:any;
  
  constructor() {
   
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    console.log("thisdata");
    console.log(this.data)
    this.rateData =this.data;
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1jw62m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauto%2Fauto.component.ts

Comment: It depends on what you want to happen while the information is not available. If it shouldn't display anything, consider a `*ngIf`, as in `<app-auto *ngIf="allData?.length" [data]="allData"></app-auto>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 - pass ASYNC data to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692222/angular2-pass-async-data-to-child-component)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ngOnInit` lifecycle-hook runs at a specific point in time, after the constructor. Your GET-request is async and resolves *at some unknown time*, probably way after your child component is created. Thus, way past you child's `ngOnInit` has run. Thus, `ngOnInit` really has nothing to work with.

You have two options of fixing this: By using the `ngOnChanges` hook (a bit complex, not recommended), or by using a setter for the input, which will run whenever the input value changes. The latter I would recommend.

I have forked your project to demonstrate: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-va1se8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauto%2Fauto.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fauto%2Fauto.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `OnChanges` interface and add `ngOnChanges` class method and manually update your field. OnInit recieves `null` and it does not get called later.

Docs: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public readonly allData$: Observable<string[]>; 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.allData$ = this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/data.json');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

<app-auto [data]="allData$ | async"></app-auto>
```

auto.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto',
  templateUrl: './auto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auto.component.css']
})
export class AutoComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() data: Array<string> = [];
  public rateData: string[] = [];
  
  constructor() {
  }
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.rateData = changes.data.currentValue;
  }
}
```

auto.component.html

```
{{ rateData | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add an onChanges to your child component and track the changes but if its just a matter of reacting to one single property change you can convert your @Input to setter/getter also e.g.

```
  private _data: string[];
  @Input() set data(val: string[]) {
    this._data = val;
    this.rateData = val;
  }
  get data(): string[] {
    return this._data;
  }
```

Updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfgmrs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fauto%2Fauto.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fauto%2Fauto.component.ts

However i would suggest that you change your parent component's change detection to OnPush and manually trigger change detection also.  In Auto change detection, angualr is running cd unncessarily and you can trigger it only when you receive the data.